# Tkinter Tooltip with Pmw Balloon does not work

Tags: python, tkinter, tooltip

I want to create a simple example with Pmw Balloon, in which a tooltip is shown if the cursor is on a widget (e.g. button):

```
from tkinter import *
import Pmw

root = Tk()
Pmw.initialise(root)

# Create some random widget
button = Button(root, text = " This is a Test", pady = 30).pack(pady = 10)

# create ballon object and bind it to the widget 
balloon = Pmw.Balloon(root)
balloon.bind(button,"Text for the tool tip")

mainloop()
```

However, i am getting an error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-1972bd06d4e6> in <module>
     10 # create ballon object and bind it to the widget
     11 balloon = Pmw.Balloon(root)
---> 12 balloon.bind(button,"Text of the tool tip")
     13 
     14 mainloop()

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/Pmw/Pmw_2_0_1/lib/PmwBalloon.py in bind(self, widget, balloonHelp, statusHelp)
     75         if statusHelp is None:
     76             statusHelp = balloonHelp
---> 77         enterId = widget.bind('<Enter>',
     78                 lambda event, self = self, w = widget,
     79                         sHelp = statusHelp, bHelp = balloonHelp:

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'bind'
```

Does someone of you know what went wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AttributeError: NoneType object has no attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1101765/7414759)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tkinter doesn't allow you to chain the pack with the button definition because `pack` doesn't return the button object.

Just break it into two lines and your code executes successfully.

Try:

```py
# Create some random widget
button = Button(root, text=" This is a Test", pady=30)
button.pack(pady=10)
```

Result:

[image]